# datetime module is being ignored in zendesk python script script

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, zendesk

In my code I'm trying to request ticket data from zendesk via zenpy wrapper. I've got a script that pulls all the data I want, but for some reason it's ignoring the part regarding the date. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



creds = {
    'email' : 'login',
    'password' : 'info',
    'subdomain': 'domain'
}

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
today = datetime.now()


from zenpy import Zenpy
zenpy = Zenpy(**creds)


for ticket in zenpy.search("test", type="ticket", created_greater_than=(yesterday)):
    print(ticket.id)
    id = ticket.id
    subj = ticket.subject
    created = ticket.created_at
    for comment in zenpy.tickets.comments(ticket.id):
        body = comment.body
```

Answer (score 0):

While it may not fix your problem, using variable names of yesterday and today when your timedelta is 1 *hour* is extremely misleading. You probably want

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
today = datetime.now()
```

instead of

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
today = datetime.now()
```

This also has a subtle fail run if run at the exact moment the clock rolls over to a new day which can be avoided by setting today first

```
today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Appreciated. It was originally days=1, but that was being skipped too. I changed it to hours in the off chance it was something to do with the api limits in zendesk. Still fails, frustratingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

for ticket in Z.search(type='ticket', created_between=[yesterday, today]):
     ...
```

This worked for me last time I used zenpy.

Make sure zenpy is updated as zendesk has been known to add/change endpoints. So if `created_greater_than` is an accepted argument in the zendesk api than it's possible that zenpy hasn't added it, or you're not on the latest version.

Comment: Outdated zenpy could be it. I've installed it recently, but if it's not the updated version it would explain all many of crazy. Without updating it from my home machine, using your code exactly (only minor difference)